# Добавление в ArrayList только уникальных объектов

Tags: java, arraylist

Как добавить только уникальные объекты в `ArrayList()`? То есть если `ArrayList<String>() a = new ArrayList<>(); a.add("Moscow"); a.add("Moscow);`
То

```
for(int i = 0;i<a.size();i++){
System.out.println(a.get(i));
}
```

Выведет только 1 `Moscow`
Как реализовать это?

Comment: Используй set http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/set.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В даннос случае вам нужен интерфейс Set

> Интерфейс `Set` расширяет интерфейс `Collection` и представляет набор
>   уникальных элементов. `Set` не добавляет новых методов, только вносит
>   изменения унаследованные. В частности, метод `add()` добавляет элемент в
>   коллекцию и возвращает `true`, если в коллекции еще нт такого элемента.

Вот небольшой пример кода

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Program{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashSet<String> states = new HashSet<String>();

        // добавим в список ряд элементов
        states.add("Germany");
        states.add("France");
        states.add("Italy");
        // пытаемся добавить элемент, который уже есть в коллекции
        boolean isAdded = states.add("Germany");
        System.out.println(isAdded);    // false

        System.out.printf("Set contains %d elements \n", states.size());    // 3

        for(String state : states){

            System.out.println(state);
        }
        // удаление элемента
        states.remove("Germany");

        // хеш-таблица объектов Person
        HashSet<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Mike"));
        people.add(new Person("Tom"));
        people.add(new Person("Nick"));
        for(Person p : people){

            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }
    }
}
class Person{

    private String name;
    public Person(String value){

        name=value;
    }
    String getName(){return name;}
}
```

[исходный код взят из источника](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.4.php)

А если потом вам надо из этого  Set-а получить ArrayList то можно сделать так

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(set);
```

Comment: А как я могу получить объект с конкретной позицией как в `ArrayList`(`.get`)?

Comment: @Felay, просто положите сет в лист и пользуйтесь листом как обычно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб привееет как . делаааа?????? ты в Москве или как ?

Comment: @elik, привет) Нет, я в СПб)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Этот если я прийду к решению использовать set, то я как то должен буду получать от туда значение по индексу, т.к. буду использовать в адаптере для recyclerview

Comment: @Felay, продолжайте использовать `List` в адаптере, но при наполнении его данными загоните их сначала в `Set`, а потом уже `Set`-ом наполняйте `List` - так у вас будет `List` c уникальными значениями

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

можно и так

```
if (!list.contains(value)) list.add(value);
```

Comment: Но это на много медленнее, чем использование `Set`.